# Eclipse automatic generate fingerprint sha1 for every android project?

Tags: eclipse, google-drive-api

i getting in started with the google drive api, and i'm following the tutorial at https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android. I need to generate a fingerprint sha1, but i see in the preferences of eclipse (preferences > android > build) an existing fingerprint sha1, associated with my project. So i have some question in my mind:

1. Eclipse generate fingerprint sha1 for each project?
2. What's the function(s) of fingerprint sha1? Only for certification that i write the app?

Comment: Android SDK generates a keystore for user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse, by default, generates a key for debugging purposes and it's located on `~/.android/debug.keystore`. Each Android app needs to be signed with a certificate to confirm authorship. Eclipse generates a keystore per user and signs the app's with the default cert from that keystore during development.